# string not assignable to parameter type Excel.XIFixedFormatType

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, excel

I am converting an excel file to a pdf file but when i am passing in the string for exporting i get this error(red underline convertFilePath) `Argument type string is not assignable to parameter type Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XIFixedFormatType`

```
var convertFileId = Guid.NewGuid();
var convertFilePath = @"c:\temp\" + convertFileId + ".pdf";



public Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook excelWorkbook { get; set; }
    void ExcelToPdf(string convertFilePath)
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application appWord = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        excelWorkbook = appWord.Workbooks.Open(DocumentUNCPath.Text);

        excelWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat(convertFilePath, WdExportFormat.wdExportFormatPDF);
        excelWorkbook.Close();
        appWord.Quit();
    }
```

Comment: In ASP.net, shouldn't it be the reverse? `ExportAsFixedFormat(FileFormat,FilePath)`

Comment: @SiddharthRout i still got the same error even when i switched them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`XlFixedFormatType` is an enumeration and you should pass a valid value.

See [MSDN on XlFixedFormatType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb241296%28v=office.12%29.aspx) and [MSDN on ExportAsFixedFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb238907%28v=office.12%29.aspx) for more information.

Example:

```
excelWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat(xlTypePdf, Filename:=filename);
```